I am not able to pick autogen completely in linux machine, does there any issue with linux in terms of auto gen
when i am trying to install autogen using
pip install pyautogen
When I am trying to import:
from autogen import ConversableAgent
Then I am getting error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConversableAgent' from 'autogen' (/home/aicoe-lnx/Documents/Dump1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/autogen/__init__.py)

Anyone faced same error?
Solution: how to import all of the autogen.

No errors on Ubuntu 20.04  with Python 3.8  and pip 20.0.2

Thanks for your answer, but this error is coming at py 3.10 and Linux 22.04
